# activity launched repeatedly when clicking button multiple times

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have a login button on main activity that executes an aysncTask which starts another activity onPostExecute, but when the user clicks button more than once 
it launches the activity multiple times, how can I prevent this from happening?

this is my onClick Listener:

```
loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (IP != "null") {
                    password = enterPassword.getText().toString();
                    progressB.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                new httpLogin().execute();}
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "please enter H2O host address before attempting to login", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

and this is the AsyncTask code:

```
public class httpLogin extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {
        String rs,result;
        JSONArray jArray;
        boolean r,isConnected;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressB.setProgress(0);
            isConnected=isOnline();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

            try {

                String link = "http://"+IP+"/H2O.asmx/Check_Waiter?Password="+password;
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
                request.setURI(new URI(link));
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                result = sb.toString();
                String[] separated = result.split(">");
                JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(separated[2]);
                jArray = jObject.getJSONArray("Waiter");
                if(jArray.length()>0) {
                    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(0);
                    waiterID = json_data.getString("UserNo");
                    waiterName = json_data.getString("UserName");
                    r=true;
                }
                else r=false;
                rs = "sucessful";
            } catch (Exception e) {

                rs = "Fail";
            }
            return rs;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            if(isConnected)
            if (r) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User ID:" + waiterID + "\n Username:" + waiterName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

               Intent intentFSelector = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FloorSelector.class);

        startActivity(intentFSelector); 
            } 
    }
```

this is ping method that checks if local server is available:

```
public boolean isOnline() {
        String[] separated = IP.split(":");
        String hostip=separated[0];
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        try {

            Process ipProcess = runtime.exec("/system/bin/ping -c 1 "+hostip);
            int     exitValue = ipProcess.waitFor();
            return (exitValue == 0);

        } catch (IOException e)          { e.printStackTrace(); }
        catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disable the button once your `AsyncTask` executes.

```
if (IP != "null") {
    password = enterPassword.getText().toString();
    progressB.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    new httpLogin().execute();
    ((Button) view).setEnabled(false);
}
```

Ideally, you should straightaway call `startActivity()` on the button click & execute the `AsyncTask` in `onCreate()`. You would display "loading..." in one of the data views there while the data is being downloaded. Once done, you update the view in `onPostExecute()` or display an error message if the download fails; say if the user was offline.

Comment: thanks. I used the setEnabled(false), as for setClickable it didnt work, the button was still clickable multiple times.

Comment: Okay, thanks for sharing that. I checked the docs and it seems setClickable() only affects the button visually i.e. whether it should be seen as pressed when clicked.

Answer (score 2):

Try this and insert in your intent :

`intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);`

Answer (score 1):

you can avoid multiple clicks to login button by using ProgressDialog.

```
ProgressDialog authProgressDialog;
```

In AsyncTask

```
public class httpLogin extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {
    String rs,result;
    JSONArray jArray;
    boolean r,isConnected;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        authProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "Loading....", true, false);   
    }

protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
      //your code
    }

 protected void onPostExecute(Object result){

            if (authProgressDialog!=null) {
                if (authProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
                        authProgressDialog.dismiss();       
                }
            }
    }
   }
```

This will display a progress dialog when ever you click on button and this dialog will close after execution of AsyncTask